# Can the uiselector class be extended to use a UI object's id?

Tags: android, adk, android-uiautomator

The uiselector class in Android's uiautomator uses classname, text, index, and other attributes to identify an object.  Is it possible to extend the uiselector class to be able to use the object's id as a selector?  If not, is there some way to get the id of displayed objects?

Answer (score 0):

no. it is not possible to use object id as selector (unless you recompile UiAutomator tool)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to retrieve an object using id for API Level 17 and below.

From API Level 18, uiautomator provides you the option to use ID's.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#resourceId(java.lang.String)